# What program is responsible for drawing the wallpaper with Cinnamon

Tags: x11, cinnamon, desktop

I was curious to look at the code which draws the desktop background, or wallpaper, using the Cinnamon desktop environment. (partially due to some ugly behavior when combining hidpi and tiled images).

What is the program which draws this? and is that the same program which is responsible for tiling (repeating the image to fill the screen) the image, or is that separate, and if so, what is that?

Comment: Try this: https://pypi.org/project/superpaper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that draws the background is in the cinnamon-dekstop library, specifically the source file gnome-bg.c

https://linuxmint-developer-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cinnamon.html clarified this for me, and [this](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-desktop/blob/master/libcinnamon-desktop/gnome-bg.c) is the gnome-bg.c file mentioned above.